# Calculate the average value in an array

Tags: ios, objective-c, nsarray

I need to add something to my app that calculates the average of an array of numbers.

If I have 3 numbers: 10, 20, and 30, how do I take all the numbers in the array, add them together (60) and then divide by the total number and present the final number somewhere like a label?

Comment: I don't really know how to do that… but whats the problem with numbers from a mutable array ?

Comment: There is nothing wrong with using numbers from a mutable array.  In fact, that **is** a form of a model backing your collevtion view that @Rob is referring to.  That being said, you should describe the data that is stored in the array as he asked.  (Are they NSNumber's?)

Answer (score 20, accepted):

In addition to katzenhut's suggestion of manually calculating the average, you can use KVC collection operators, too, e.g.:

```
NSArray *array = @[@10, @25, @30];

NSNumber *average = [array valueForKeyPath:@"@avg.self"];
```

Or, if dealing with objects, for example a "Product" model object with this interface:

```
@interface Product : NSObject

@property (nonatomic, copy) NSString *name;
@property (nonatomic) double price;

- (id)initWithName:(NSString *)name price:(double)price; // the corresponding implementation should be obvious, so I'll not include it in this code snippet

@end
```

You could then do:

```
NSMutableArray *products = [NSMutableArray array];
[products addObject:[[Product alloc] initWithName:@"item A" price:1010.0]];
[products addObject:[[Product alloc] initWithName:@"item B" price:1025.0]];
[products addObject:[[Product alloc] initWithName:@"item C" price:1030.0]];

NSNumber *average = [products valueForKeyPath:@"@avg.price"];
```

---

If you want to take the results and populate a label with the results, you might do something like:

```
NSNumberFormatter *formatter = [[NSNumberFormatter alloc] init];
formatter.numberStyle = NSNumberFormatterDecimalStyle;
formatter.maximumFractionDigits = 2;                   // two decimal places?

self.averageLabel.text = [formatter stringFromNumber:average];
```

The advantage of `NSNumberFormatter` over `stringWithFormat` is that you have greater control over the string representation of the number, e.g. it can observe localization, employ thousandths separators, etc.

Answer (score 3):

you shuold have an array that contains the values for your cells, and you should update that array whenever a cell is edited. So add these values up for later use (say, in a float named `total`).

```
float total;
total = 0;
for(NSNumber *value in myArray){
    total+=[value floatValue];
}
```

Divide total by count, and you're done. like `float average = total/myArray.count`

Comment: By the way, float's can not be stored in an NSArray....

Comment: it gives me an error that I can't put float in a for or something

Comment: as @lnafziger pointed out, you need to work with Objects when dealing with collection classes. i changed the example to account for that.

Comment: But why do it manually when NSArray will happily calculate the average for you? Collection operators like `@avg` let you write more compact, readable, reliable code.

Comment: @Caleb - i know now, and i gave +1 to Robs superior solution.

Answer (score 0):

You should have a proper data model. For example, if you have 30 cells, there is no need to display all the 30 cells in your tableview. Doing that will be a waste of resources and that why we always implement dequereuseable method in tableview delegates.

Having said that, do something like this

```
#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>

@interface ViewController : UITableViewController

@end
```

Implementation as below

```
 #import "ViewController.h"

@interface ViewController ()
{
    NSArray *numbersList;
}

-(float) calculateAvg;

@end

@implementation ViewController

- (id)initWithStyle:(UITableViewStyle)style
   {
    self = [super initWithStyle:style];
    if (self) {
        // Custom initialization
    }
    return self;
}

- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];

    numbersList = [[NSArray alloc]initWithObjects:@"10",@"23",@"34",@"43",@"57",@"64",@"77",@"88",@"95",nil];
    [[self tableView] setDelegate:self];
    [[self tableView] setDataSource:self];
}
```

#pragma mark - Table view data source

```
- (NSInteger)numberOfSectionsInTableView:(UITableView *)tableView
{
    // Return the number of sections.
    return 1;
}

- (NSInteger)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView numberOfRowsInSection:(NSInteger)section
{
    // Return the number of rows in the section. Plus one to hold average
    return [numbersList count] + 1;
}

 - (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:@"cell"];

    if(cell == nil)
    {
        cell = [[UITableViewCell alloc]initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleDefault reuseIdentifier:@"cell"];
    }

    if([indexPath row] < [numbersList count])
    {
        [[cell textLabel] setText:[numbersList objectAtIndex:[indexPath row]]];
    }
    else
    {
        float avg = [self calculateAvg];
        [[cell textLabel] setText:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%f",avg]];
    }


    return cell;

}

-(float) calculateAvg
{
    float avg = 0;

    for(int idx=0;idx<[numbersList count];idx++)
    {
        int tempValue = [[numbersList objectAtIndex:idx] intValue];
        avg = avg + tempValue;
    }

    return (avg / [numbersList count]);
}
```